# Permission denied error when uploading image to server

Tags: java, php, android

In my app I'm trying to take a picture and send it over to the server coded as a String when I run it, I am able to take the picture but as soon as I click ok the app crashes and I get the following error:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/test123.jpeg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                  Process: info.androidhive.loginandregistration, PID: 8775
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                      at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.activity.ImageActivity$Encode_image.doInBackground(ImageActivity.java:86)
                      at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.activity.ImageActivity$Encode_image.doInBackground(ImageActivity.java:79)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Heres my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.loginandregistration"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="info.androidhive.loginandregistration.app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.test"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.SearchActivity"
            android:label="MY SICK APP"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ImageActivity"
            android:label="MY SICK APP"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:largeHeap="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

-

```
public class ImageActivity extends Activity{
    final String URL = "linktophpfile";
    private Button button;
    private String coded_string, name;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private File file;
    private Uri uri;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_main);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view){
                Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                getUri();
                i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,uri);
                startActivityForResult(i,5);
            }
        });

    }

    public void getUri() {
        String name = "test123.jpeg";
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ file.separator + name);
        uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode==5 && resultCode== RESULT_OK){
            new Encode_image().execute();

        }
    }

    private class Encode_image extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.getPath());
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
            bitmap.recycle();

            byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
            coded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array,0);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            makeRequest();
        }
    }

    private void makeRequest() {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

            }

        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("coded_String", coded_string);
                map.put("image_name", name);
                return map;
            }
        };
        queue.add(request);


    }

}
```

php code:

```
<?php
 header('Content-type : bitmap; charset=utf-8');

 if(isset($_POST["encoded_string"])){

    $encoded_string = $_POST["encoded_string"];
    $image_name = $_POST["image_name"];

    $decoded_string = base64_decode($encoded_string);

    $path = 'images/'.$image_name;

    $file = fopen($path, 'wb');

    $is_written = fwrite($file, $decoded_string);
    fclose($file);

    if($is_written > 0) {

        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password','dbname');
        $query = "INSERT INTO images(name,path) values('$image_name','$path');";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) ;

        if($result){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "failed";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);
    }
 }
?>
```

Any ideas of what could be wrong? thanks

Comment: This is a `java.IO` problem. Did you declare read permissions in your `manifest.xml` ?

Comment: Which os version you are using ??? If you are using marshmallow then ask for runtime permission for image capture and read write storage permission...

Comment: @Bhavnik these are declared in the manifest no?

Comment: Yes you've declared in manifest but marshmallow version requires runtime permission for camera access, read write external storage, get current location etc... You can find plenty of examples for that.

Comment: @Bhavnik actually the sdk is 21 so should be lollipop

Comment: If you are not working on marshmallow then possibly file do not exist in your device, that's why you are getting FileNotFoundException, make sure file is created after image capturing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Declared in your `manifest.xml` file

Comment: I believe I only need the WRITE permission but the error persists with the READ permission regardless.

Comment: @Gabrielbu Can you please edit your post to include the `manifest.xml`

Comment: @Gabrielbu I'd try to put the all `uses-permission` right after the `manifest`  tag, followed by `uses-sdk` and then the `uses-feature` . The order is somewhat important

Comment: I dont think the order of that matters, but I tried it regardless and get the same error

Comment: @Gabrielbu The only other thing I can see is this is caused by a `NullPointerExcepiton`  which probably means it can't fetch your image after you save it. Check if the URI is working, and if it's not, use `MediaScanner` to detect the image after it's saved.

Comment: when I debug it, it gives me this: uri:file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/test123.jpeg is this what i should be getting?

Answer (score 0):

1 check your app's permission states in phone settings.
2 Check this photo's real uri in debug mode.

Comment: 1 Dont know what you mean by this but i also tried to run on emulator so shouldnt have anything to do with phones permissions
2 I can't check this as the app crashes as soon as the picture is taken